# How can I suppress Postfix anvil statistics from system logs?

Tags: postfix, logging, syslog

After every email sent through my mail server, `postfix/anvil` appends something like the following:

```
Nov  9 15:09:11 keutenberg postfix/anvil[30006]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:103.28.42.75) at Nov  9 15:02:42
Nov  9 15:09:11 keutenberg postfix/anvil[30006]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:103.28.42.75) at Nov  9 15:02:42
Nov  9 15:09:11 keutenberg postfix/anvil[30006]: statistics: max message rate 1/60s for (smtp:103.28.42.75) at Nov  9 15:02:43
Nov  9 15:09:11 keutenberg postfix/anvil[30006]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Nov  9 15:02:42
```

I understand why these messages are being logged (I set up the restrictions), but I can't find any way to change `anvil`'s log level (i.e. to suppress these informational messages from `mail.log`). Is there a setting I can use in my `main.cf` to disable these statistical messages? I'd rather stop them at the source than suppress them through a syslog setting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to change the frequency of the logs you can set `anvil_status_update_time` in `main.cf`. The default is 600s. http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#anvil_status_update_time

Two hours worked better for me, than using the default 10 minutes, but it will vary depending on the environment obviously.

```
anvil_rate_time_unit = 60s
anvil_status_update_time =  2h
```

Also, in order to solve an issue I had with long delay in logging of incoming mail, I had to configure the following settings. If you notice your incoming mail logs aren't updating when they should be, try this:

```
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 2s
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 10
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 20
```

---

***If your server gets less than 1 email per 600s**

The anvil daemon by default logs statistics when it exits. Since the default idle time is 600s, **you will continue to receive anvil logs every 10 minutes in the event no email is received**.

This can be changed to a longer time-span by adding `-o max_idle` to `master.cf`

```
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil -o max_idle=3600s
```

Answer (score 4):

#### *Beware this setting will override your [ability to limit client connection](http://www.postfix.org/TUNING_README.html#conn_limit).*

There is a parameter in `main.cf` to *suppress* the anvil process. This parameter is called  [smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions). The purpose of this parameter is to exclude some client from smtpd_client_*_count/rate_limit restrictions. In your case, you should specify it in `main.cf`

```
smtpd_client_event_limit_exceptions = static:all
```

This will make all IP address listed as **clients that are excluded from smtpd_client_*_count/rate_limit restrictions**. Thus this setting will *suppress* anvil log because there is nothing to log.

Source: [similar question in postfix mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mailing.postfix.users/O49e9SZjjvw).

Comment: while this is true, you could aswell simply remove the limits as they are no longer enforced anyway. i was wondering about the very same thing recently, but there really is no way to disable them in the source code of common installs right now. assuming you have a larger mailserver running, you will eventually only read filtered syslog anyway, so try adding something like `^\w{3} [ :0-9]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ postfix/anvil\[[0-9]{1,8}\]: statistics: [a-zA-Z0-9 /:\.]{15,99}$` to `/etc/logcheck/ignore.d/postfix`

Answer (score 2):

I am using **rsyslogd(8)** to put specific messages in a different logfile.

For example, create a new file `/etc/rsyslog.d/maillog-stats.conf` with this contents:

```
# extract then discard stats from anvil daemon
:msg, contains, "statistics: max"              /var/log/maillog-stats
:msg, contains, "statistics: max"              stop
```

Files in the `/etc/rsyslog.d` directory are read before `/etc/rsyslog.conf` so these filters happen before the main config file.

The first property-based filter writes messsages containing "statistics: max" in `/var/log/maillog-stats` and the second one discards the message for further treatment with the `stop` action.

Remaining messages are treated as before by the rule in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`,

```
# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                    -/var/log/maillog
```

You also may wish to set some rotation rule, eg by creating the file: `/etc/logrotate.d/maillog` :

```
/var/log/maillog-stats
{
    weekly
    rotate 10
    missingok
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```